# Integer overflow no R

Tags: r

Estou trabalhando numa simulação de dinâmica populacional que envolve geração de números inteiros. Devido às hipóteses do meu modelo, estou gerando números aleatórios através da função `rmultinom` do R. Entretanto, estou com problemas de overflow na minha simulação.

O maior inteiro que o R consegue gerar é definido por `.Machine$integer.max`. No meu PC, este número é igual a 2147483648. Em notação científica, este valor equivale a, aproximadamente, 2,147 x 10^9.

Só que muitas das simulações que eu rodo ultrapassam este limite. O parâmetro `size` da `rmultinom` vai ser maior do que 10^(10) ou até mesmo 10^(12). E, se assim forem, não consigo gerar números aleatórios com a distribuição que desejo.

O que eu poderia fazer para resolver este problema? Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, o que o `rmultinom` faz, é o seguinte:

- Você possui `lenght(prob)` tipos distintos de bolas, em que `prob` é o parâmtero `prob` da função.
- Em seguida você vai retirar `size` bolas de forma independente, de acordo com estas probabilidades. (`size` é o parâmetro `size` da função)
- Esse procedimento será repetido `n`, vezes. (`n` é p parâmetro `n` da função)

Dado este cenário imagino que você possa usar `sizes` maiores do que o que cabe no `R`, da seguinte maneira:

Uma possível função que tira amostras com o tamanho máximo do `R`

```
library(bit64)
rmultinom2 <- function(size, prob){

  n <- size %/% 1000000000L
  resto <- size %% 1000000000L

  amostra <- rmultinom(n = as.integer(n), size = 1000000000L, prob = prob)
  amostra_resto <- rmultinom(n = 1, size = resto, prob = prob)

  return(rowSums(cbind(amostra, amostra_resto)))
}
```

Repetindo o experimento 100x

```
amostra <- plyr::ldply(1:100, function(x, size, prob) {
  rmultinom2(size, prob)
}, size = as.integer64("10000000000"), prob = c(1,2,4,5)
)
```

Acho que a grande sacada aqui, é usar o pacote `bit64` que suporta inteiros maiores e retirar várias amostras independes para depois somar. É possível que também seja necessário transformar as linhas da `amostra` (dentro da função) em inteiros grandes para que a soma também não exploda.

Agora, se `lenght(prob)` for maior do que o maior inteiro, eu não sei.

Comment: Sim, sim, esta é a definição da distribuição multinomial. O `length(prob)` não será problema pra mim, pois ele está fixado como 3. Rodei a tua função aqui e, em meus testes, ela parou de dar overflow nos casos em que isto ocorria.

Comment: Boa! Acho que vai dar problema se for o size for > 1000000000L^2
Faz sentido fazer os ensaios de forma independente e depois somar né?

Comment: Faz todo o sentido, pois são sorteios independentes. Uma maneira de verificar isto é rodar a tua função `amostra` um número grande de vezes (digamos 100000, em vez de 100) para um valor menor de size. Aí roda a versão original da `rmultinom` para os mesmos valores de replicação, size e prob. Se as estimativas por categorias baterem com o que foi definido em `prob`, vai estar tudo certo. Eu rodei aqui e tudo bateu como deveria.